# Can't use ember-components in my app

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

After installing ember-components via bower, I'm trying to use it;

depending on the component I get different errors;
for example if I try to use the tab component (simple version), I get this:

```
Assertion Failed: `blockHelperMissing` was invoked without a helper name, which is most likely due to a mismatch between the version of Ember.js you're running now and the one used to precompile your templates. Please make sure the version of `ember-handlebars-compiler` you're using is up to date.
Error: Assertion Failed: `blockHelperMissing` was invoked without a helper name, which is most likely due to a mismatch between the version of Ember.js you're running now and the one used to precompile your templates. Please make sure the version of `ember-handlebars-compiler` you're using is up to date.
```

With other components (such as accordion) I get errors like this:

```
Uncaught Error: <App.ItaHomeView:ember360> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'em-accordion' on object <App.HomeController:ember408>.
```

I'm using Ember 1.7.0, with handlebars 1.3.0 and ember-components 0.2.0

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Some code or jsbin please

Comment: Finally I discovered that was due to some wrong paths in the index.js file (3 lines around line 31)